# How to use AngularJS scope.$bind

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following controller which works fine:

```
function Controller() {}

Controller.prototype = {
    getResult: function(project) {
        var that = this;

        jQuery.ajax({
            async: false,
            url: "/my-service/call?project=" + project,
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(data) { 
                that.result = data;
            }
        });
    }
};
```

I'd like to use AngularJS  .scope.$bind to see if I could eliminate the 'var that = this;' hack.  But the following doesn't work:

```
function Controller() {}

Controller.prototype = {
    getResult: function(project) {
        angular.scope.$bind(jQuery.ajax({
            async: false,
            url: "/my-service/call?project=" + project,
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(data) { 
                this.result = data;
            }
        }))();
    }
};
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Please don't ask the same question multiple times. Thanks.

Comment: @Graham The user in this question is asking about `angular.scope` as a programming construct, not as the name of the library. Tags are meant to be used for searchability.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Misko Hevery on the angular mailing responded with:

```
Controller.prototype = {
    getStuff: function(project) {
        jQuery.ajax({
                    async: false,
                    url: "/service/get-stuff",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: angular.bind(this, function(data) {
                        this.stuff = data;
                    })
                });
    }
};
```

He also suggested using angular.service.$xhr instead of jQuery.ajax.